# Nested type definition: Type "A" cannot be used to index type B

Tags: typescript

We have a bunch of Cloudant databases we move around the app as DBInfo type, which used to be defined like this:

```
type DBInfo = {
  client: CloudantV1
  name: string
}
```

and the object containing all DBs which is passed around was defined as such:

```
export type DBS = {
  main: DBInfo
  change: DBInfo
}
```

We have way more DB but I will use two for the example.

Issue with that is the function to call views and so on are completely generic and are defined with strings:

```
function (db: DBInfo, design: string, viewName: string) {}
```

This leads to lots of bugs in the code where the design documents or views don't exist for the given DB.

I'm trying to define generic types so the given DBInfo defines the design documents, views, indexes, ... that can be used to avoid bugs. I tried to define a complex type defining all parameters of the DBs (design docs, views, indexes, ...). We have many DB so I simplified for the example here:

```
export type DbSpecs = {
  main: {
    designDocs: {
      myDesignDoc: {
        views: 'product' | 'user' | 'presetTransformForProduct'
      },
      schedules: {
        views: 'byProduct' | 'all' | 'byPipeline'
      }
    },
  },
  change: {
    designDocs: {
      changes: {
        views: 'byProduct'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From there I tried restricting conditionally the design doc and view parameters like this:

```
type DbName = keyof DbSpecs
type DesignDoc<D extends DbName> = Extract<keyof DbSpecs[D]['designDocs'], string>
type View<D extends DbName, DD extends DesignDoc<D>> = DbSpecs[D]['designDocs'][DD]['views']
```

I'm not expert enough to understand why it doesn't understand in the DbSpecs type that all keys are only strings, but I had to add the Extract or I would get `Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.` when using the DesignDoc parameter in my function, because the Cloudant library expect a string only:

[image: string error]

Based on this I updated the DBInfo like this, so I can infer the type of DB from the given

```
export type DBInfo<Name extends DbName> = {
  client: CloudantV1,
  name: Name
}
```

And the DBS object containing all db was refactored as:

```
export type DBS = {
  main: DBInfo<'main'>
  change: DBInfo<'change'>
}
```

It's not ideal that I have to repeat the name of the DB but I guess if they are all DBInfo I'll have no way to make a different between the parameters.

Now the main issue is the following, for some reason although the `keyof` works fine for the first level, `designDocs`, it fails wen it's two level down (the `views` key) with the following error:
`Type '"views"' cannot be used to index type 'DbSpecs[D]["designDocs"][DD]`

[image: view error]

The strange thing is that VSCode still seems to be able to auto complete perfectly fine the following function:

```
export const test = <
  D extends keyof DbSpecs,
  DD extends DesignDoc<D>,
  V extends View<D, DD>
  >( db: DBInfo<D>, ddoc: DD, view: V) => {
  return db.client.postView({
    db: db.name,
    ddoc,
    view,
    key: ''
  })
}
```

It does complain as well about the view parameter:
[image: view error]

But has no issue completing like it should:

[image: main design doc]

[image: change design doc]

[image: main views]

[image: change views]

Any idea why the error, while the auto-complete works like I would expect?

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
type DbSpecs = {
    dba: {
        designDocs: {
            design1: { views: 'view1' | 'view2' },
            design2: { views: 'view3' | 'view4' }
        }
    },
    dbb: {
        designDocs: {
            design3: { views: 'view5' | 'view6' },
            design4: { views: 'view7' | 'view8' }
        }
    }
}

type DbName = keyof DbSpecs
type DesignDoc<D extends DbName> = Extract<keyof DbSpecs[D]['designDocs'], string>
type View<D extends DbName, DD extends DesignDoc<D>> = DbSpecs[D]['designDocs'][DD]['views']
```

You can see that the last line gives `Type '"views"' cannot be used to index type 'DbSpecs[D]["designDocs"][DD]'.ts(2536)`, although if you add those 2 lines after:

```
const f = <D extends DbName, DD extends DesignDoc<D>, V extends View<D, DD>>(
    db: D, ddoc: DD, view: V) => view
f('dba', 'design1', '')
```

You can see that the third parameter auto-complete like it should (and type-check fine) to the following value

```
dba/design1 => view1/view2
dba/design2 => view3/view4
dbb/design3 => view5/view6
dbb/design4 => view7/view8
```

Sorry for the long post but I didn't know how to explain without some context.

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs aren't really appropriate here; [please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).  Also, please provide a [mre] without issues unrelated to your question: right now  `CloudantV1` is some undeclared private or third party type; if your question really depends on it, then you might want to tag it as such.  If not, then you should probably define it or, even better, remove it from your question code. Good luck!

Comment: I think it's just that TS tries to be as smart as it can about generics, but generics are hard so it can't quite work them out in uncommon use-cases like yours. You may try to check explicitly that `DbSpecs[D]['designDocs'][DD]` is of type `{views: string}` and has a `views` property, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w6pYEm)

Comment: @jcalz I definitely understand that screenshots of IDE aren't really appropriate, but it's hard to show autocompletion working without screenshots ;-) I also wrote all errors as text to make sure they are searchable, the screenshot of error were there to give more context before showing that auto-completion works in VSCode although I had those errors. I will edit to remove them and only show the text then.

I will add a minimal reproducible example as soon as I can.

Comment: @AlexChashin The explicit check works great. thanks! I'm still not sure why I would need it and why VSCode doesn't see that all object of all `designDocs` have `views` keys, but maybe there is something I'm missing here

Comment: @GuillaumeDelory, I don't think there is anything you are missing, to me it just looks like TS is not quite smart enough to work it out. Generics in TS are funky, because working with them is a trade-off between correct types and good compiler performance, so there is a lot of caching and lazy computations going on. I would assume that your code doesn't work, precisely because computations that would ensure that all objects in `designDocs` have `views` key are postponed and not resolved yet when the object is subscripted with `['views']`. Anyway, glad the explicit check helped